# How do I put my menu links on a horizontal line with CSS?

Tags: css, menu

What I'm trying to do is put my menu on a horizontal line rather than on a vertical line. Anyone knows how to do this?

http://nemofirm.com/cssheaderandfooter.php

Comment: `li { display: inline }` is probably a start. But you should post some code here so the question and its answers have a value to future generations

Comment: You should wrap your `li`s into a `ul` by the way, that's their parent element

Comment: I know someone who hates CSS. The fun starts when you want it to work in IE6!

Comment: It's not CSS's fault that you don't understand how to use it.

Comment: I didn't know CSS was a company.

Comment: CSS is an art itself. Being a programmer is not enough. :)

Comment: Aww, @BoltClock took out all the good parts.

Comment: @erekalper: That's OK, there's always the revision history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kZzXs/ or http://jsfiddle.net/kZzXs/2/

As others have said: `float: left` or `display:inline` both do the trick. I also added the missing `<ul>` tags. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I´d say reasonably valid html is a good starting point. You do realize that you have 2 `html` tags and 2 `body` tags, right?

And the missing `ul` is already mentioned by others.

<strike>You must be driving the browser nuts as well ;-)</strike>

Answer (score 3):

first of all you must have your li elemnts in ul

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

you can either float to the left; `float:left;` or give them `display:inline;`

Answer (score -2):

`li` tags should have `display: inline` style.

If we're talking about CSS, yeah, it sucks. But there's nothing better for now (I hope that some day, Web will be all about XML resources, XSLT translations and some kind of CSS++, which will describe how element should be seen rather than how it should be processed by browser).

Comment: Psh.  XML shouldn't be used for web pages.  XHTML proved that even when stuff's supposed to be correct (under threat of breakage), it won't be.  And now we instead have XML that isn't really XML, and web weenies sticking /> on the end of all their img and input tags thinking that makes everything correct, but totally neglecting the CDATA wrappers around their JS, the changes to the DOM, the massive errors in the XML itself (special chars, text and elements intermingled, etc)...

Comment: @cHao This is not what I'm talking about. I'm more about web pages providing resources in XML and different XSLT sheets to provide portability between different devices, so things like mobile.example.com wouldn't be needed anymore.

For example your tweets won't look like `<!doctype html><html> (...) </html>`, rather like: `<tweets><tweet from="somebody">hey, checkout this new webpage!</tweet> (...) </tweets>`. So many profits.